# cuando oprimo el boton de comprar me aparece en consola solo array con valor [0} cuando deberia aparecer el nombre del producto

Tags: javascript

```js
**añado constate postres**
const postres =[   

    { id:2, nombre:"tirramisu", precio:200,img:"img/tirramisu.jpg",descripcion:"Uno de los postres más populares en Italia es el TiramisúEstá hecho con capas de galletas savoiardi o de crema mascarpone. Es original de la región del Veneto."},
    { id:2, nombre:"PannaCotta", precio:200,img:"img/pannacota.jpg",descripcion:"La panna cotta es una deliciosa que sin duda debes probar. La base de este postre es la nata, de hecho la palabra panna cotta significa literalmente “nata cocida."},
    { id:3, nombre:"Cannoli", precio:300,img:"img/cannoli.jpg",descripcion:" Se trata de una masa crujiente enrollada rellena de ricotta pastelera y también trozos de fruta en los extremos. Para su elaboración también puedes utilizar nuestra nata Ken"},
    { id:4, nombre:"Zuccoto", precio:400,img:"img/zuccoto.jpg",descripcion:"Otro irresistible postre italiano es el zuccotto elaborado usando bizcocho o soletillas mojadas en ron u otro licor de alta graduación. Además se añade una capa gruesa de nata montada, aromatizada a veces con vainilla o chocolate, fruta confitada, frutos secos o nueces, y se cubre con otra capa de bizcocho según la receta tradicional."},
    { id:5, nombre:"sfogliatelle", precio:500,img:"img/sfogliatelle.jpg",descripcion:" Es una de las muestras más características de la alta pastelería napolitana. Un postre italiano elaborado en base a un hojaldre trabajado a mano y rellenado con ricotta, fruta confitada, crema pastelera y sémola."},
    { id:6, nombre:"Profiteroles", precio:500,img:"img/profiteroles.jpg",descripcion:"Aunque franceses e italianos se “disputan” el origen de los profiteroles qué duda cabe que es otro de los postres italianos más demandados por los comensales. Por un lado se debe crear la masa y por otra la crema, aquí también podemos usar leche y nata."},
 ]
```

```js
 function compra(){

  let productosSeleccionados=document.getElementsByClassName('.btn2');

   let productosComprados = postres.find(elemento=>elemento.nombre===productosSeleccionados)
 
   let carrito=[]

   carrito.push(productosComprados)
 
   console.log("carrito",carrito)
 
   localStorage.setItem('productos seleccionados',JSON.stringify(carrito));
  }
```

```html
 <input type="Button" class="btn2 btn-primary button"  onclick=compra() mostarcantidad() name="comprar" id="btn1" value="comprar">
```

**la idea que desde el array me muestre el producto comprado en consola pero cada vez que oprimo devuelve array[0]**

Comment: ¿Puedes añadir el código completo? Falta saber como tienes definido postres y demás para poder probarlo... Así podremos ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Necesitamos algo más de tu código.

Comment: Seguramente te pase porque `productosSeleccionados` es un array, estas comparando un nombre con un array.

Comment: Ahí añadí la constante postres...la idea es que al oprimir el botón de comprar aparezca en consola el producto encontrado con el método find pero devuelve 'carrito[undefined] teniendo que mostrar el producto.